# issue with adding button programmatically

Tags: android, onclicklistener

actually i add some buttons programmatically with no problems.after that i need to recreate buttons and delete old buttons.also i had set OnClickListener for each button.my problem is that when i recall funcrion refresh() and recreate buttons,buttons added succefully,but when i click on buttons,program crashs! :|

```
      Main Class:

package com.example.mysqlex;

import com.example.mysqlex.DbHandler;
import com.example.mysqlex.DbHelper;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
public class Main extends Activity {
static String Totalresult;
static LinearLayout Llayout,mainRel;
static TextView titleTest;
private static Context context;
private Typeface font;


private DbHandler dbHandler=new DbHandler(this);
public DbHelper dbHelper=new DbHelper(this);
private SQLiteDatabase database;

public static boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    mainRel=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainRel);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/yekan2.TTF");
    TextView title=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setTypeface(font);
    context=this;
    if(dbHandler.getSettings("catlist", "value")=="null"){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "اطلاعاتی ذخیره نشده است.لطفا نوسازی کنید...", 5000).show();
    }else{
        refresh("home");
    }
}
public void refresh(String refreshType){
    dbHandler=new DbHandler(context);
    dbHelper=new DbHelper(context);
    if(refreshType=="button"){
        if(dbHandler.getSettings("catlist", "value")=="null"){
            dbHandler.insertSettings("catlist", Totalresult, "");
        }else{
            dbHandler.updateSettings("catlist", Totalresult, "");
        }
    }else if(refreshType=="home"){
        Totalresult=dbHandler.getSettings("catlist", "value");
    }
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/yekan2.TTF");
    String[] childs=Totalresult.split("/.../<br />");
    mainRel.removeAllViews();

    for(int i=0; i<childs.length; i++){
        String[] parts=childs[i].split("<br />");
        final String[] values=parts[1].split("->");

        final String[] id=parts[0].split("->");

        Button btn = new Button(context);
        LinearLayout Llayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cat_drawable);
        btn.setHeight(110); btn.setTextSize(24); btn.setTypeface(font); btn.setTextColor(R.color.white);
        btn.setId(i);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent goToContent = new Intent(Main.this, Content.class); 
            goToContent.putExtra("catid", id[1]);
            goToContent.putExtra("pageTitle", values[1]);
            startActivity(goToContent);
        }
    });

        LayoutParams btnLp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams LLp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LLp.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 5);
        btn.setLayoutParams(btnLp);
        Llayout.setLayoutParams(LLp);

        btn.setText(values[1]);
        Llayout.addView(btn);
        mainRel.addView(Llayout);
    }
}
public void refresh_btn(View v) {
    if(haveNetworkConnection()){
        SigninActivity.classReferrer="Main";
        new SigninActivity(this,0).execute("site_id","1","catlist","1","data_type","echo(/.../)");
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "لطفا جهت نوسازی اطلاعات،به اینترنت متصل شوید", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
}


   SigninActivity Class :
package com.example.mysqlex;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;


import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SigninActivity  extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
private ProgressDialog pdia;
String url="http://www.pbroilgas.com/index2.php";
private TextView roleField;
private Context context;
private int byGetOrPost = 0; 
static public String results,classReferrer;
static public String[] resultArray;
//flag 0 means get and 1 means post.(By default it is get.)
public SigninActivity(Context context,int flag) {
  this.context = context;
  byGetOrPost = flag;
}

protected void onPreExecute(){

   pdia = new ProgressDialog(context);
   pdia.setMessage("در حال نوسازی اطلاعات...");
   pdia.setProgressStyle(pdia.STYLE_SPINNER);
   pdia.show();
   super.onPreExecute();
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
  if(byGetOrPost == 0){ //means by Get Method
     try{
         String command1 = (String)arg0[0];
         String value1 = (String)arg0[1];
         StringBuilder link = new StringBuilder();
         link.append(url+"?"+command1+"="+value1);
         for(int i=2; i<arg0.length; i+=2){
             link.append("&"+arg0[i]);
             link.append("="+arg0[i+1]);
         }
        URL url = new URL(link.toString());
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(link.toString()));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
       (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

       StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
       String line;
       while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
           sb.append(line);
        }
        in.close();
        return sb.toString();
  }catch(Exception e){
     return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
  }
  }
  else{
     try{
        String command = (String)arg0[0];
        String value = (String)arg0[1];
        String link=url;
        String data  = URLEncoder.encode(command, "UTF-8") 
        + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8");
        URL url = new URL(link);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
        conn.setDoOutput(true); 
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter
        (conn.getOutputStream()); 
        wr.write( data ); 
        wr.flush(); 
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        // Read Server Response
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
           sb.append(line);
           break;
        }
        return sb.toString();
     }catch(Exception e){
        return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
     }
  }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
   pdia.dismiss();
   results=result;
   if(classReferrer=="Main"){
       Main  main= new Main();
       Main.Totalresult=result.toString();
       main.refresh("button");
   }else if(classReferrer=="Content"){
       Content  content= new Content();
       Content.Totalresult=result.toString();
       content.refresh("button");
   }
  }
}
```

my LogCat :
`08-11 02:12:55.839: E/AndroidRuntime(8853): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 02:12:55.839: E/AndroidRuntime(8853): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 02:12:55.839: E/AndroidRuntime(8853):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:127)
08-11 02:12:55.839: E/AndroidRuntime(8853):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
08-11 02:12:55.839: E/AndroidRuntime(8853):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3350)
08-11 02:12:55.839: E/AndroidRuntime(8853):     at com.example.mysqlex.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:99)
08-11 02:12:55.839: E/AndroidRuntime(8853):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
08-11 02:12:55.839: E/AndroidRuntime(8853):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
08-11 02:12:55.839: E/AndroidRuntime(8853):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-11 02:12:55.839: E/AndroidRuntime(8853):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-11 02:12:55.839: E/AndroidRuntime(8853):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
08-11 02:12:55.839: E/AndroidRuntime(8853):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4786)
08-11 02:12:55.839: E/AndroidRuntime(8853):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 02:12:55.839: E/AndroidRuntime(8853):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-11 02:12:55.839: E/AndroidRuntime(8853):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
08-11 02:12:55.839: E/AndroidRuntime(8853):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
08-11 02:12:55.839: E/AndroidRuntime(8853):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

i appreciate your helps...
thanks in advance...

Comment: `childs.length` does that have a value? Its a null pointer exception...so probably that is null?

Comment: thanks for reply bro...yes for sure.my proplem is onClickListener that doesnt works  for the seccond time that is set for btn

Comment: @gurinderhans if it was null,so the button views shouldn't be added to the view..right ? so its no null...

Comment: Thats right! Can you specify which line it gives the error at?

Comment: thank you really...it gives error at this line:Intent goToContent = new Intent(Main.this, Content.class);

Comment: Silly question but is that `refresh(...)` method part of an `Activity` called `Main`?

Comment: Yea is that? Just replace `Main.this` with `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @Squonk thanks for reply...yes its part of activity class..but outside of onCreate class...

Comment: @gurinderhans thank you bro.but it doesnt works too :(

Comment: Can you give us the whole code related to this problem? I will be able to better debug it then.

Comment: @user3543201 : And the `Activity` is definitely called `Main`? I notice the `refresh(...)` method is declared as `public` are you trying to call it from outside of the `Activity`? It seems `Main.this` is `null`.

Comment: @gurinderhans i edited the post with thw whole code :-)

Comment: @user3543201 : yes its deffenatly Main. and yes i call it out side of this class....

Comment: @user3543201 : See my answer - you're breaking a golden rule of Android. Never treat a class which extends `Activity` as a normal Java class - it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that it can't get the package name. So your Main.this is invalid at that point for some reason. Change it to this:

```
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent goToContent = new Intent(arg0.getContext(), Content.class);
        goToContent.putExtra("catid", id[1]);
        goToContent.putExtra("pageTitle", values[1]);
        startActivity(goToContent);
    }
```

You have an invalid context reference, but the view that calls the method should never be invalid.

Comment: thank you for your answer my friend. i  did as you said,the app crashs again,but logCat changed as below:

Comment: 08-11 02:50:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(14203): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 02:50:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(14203): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 02:50:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
08-11 02:50:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
08-11 02:50:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
08-11 02:50:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)

Comment: 08-11 02:50:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):  at com.example.mysqlex.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:102)
08-11 02:50:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
08-11 02:50:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
08-11 02:50:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-11 02:50:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-11 02:50:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):  at

Comment: android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
08-11 02:50:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4786)
08-11 02:50:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 02:50:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-11 02:50:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
08-11 02:50:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)

Comment: Now you have an error at line 102 - "startActivity" - that means the activity you are referencing when that method is called is null; as suspected, "Main" is dereferenced at this point. Try "arg0.getContext().startActivity(goToContent)"

Comment: ** THANKS MY DEAR FRIEND ** it works as well as i respected...i really appreciate you and your knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for the `Intent(Context, Class<?>)`...

```
public Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) {
    mComponent = new ComponentName(packageContext, cls);
}
```

...then looking at the source for the `ComponentName(Context, Class<?>)` constructor...

```
public ComponentName(Context pkg, Class<?> cls) {
    mPackage = pkg.getPackageName();
    mClass = cls.getName();
}
```

...the only way using `Intent(Context, Class<?>)` can throw an NPE is at `mPackage = pkg.getPackageName();` - in other words `Main.this` is null.

Looking at your updated code I can see why. In `onPostExecute(...)` of the `AsyncTask` in your `SigninActivity` you are doing the following...

```
Main main= new Main();
```

It is not possible to create an instance of an `Activity` using `new` - it simply doesn't work and that's why `Main.this` is `null`.

You're going to have to rethink things as you should never attempt to access any variables or methods of an `Activity` from any other app component.

If you need to access methods in an `Activity` from an `AsyncTask`, the easiest thing is to make the `AsyncTask` an inner class of the `Activity` itself.

Comment: ok, i wil change that part! but how can i call refresh() which is in another class,according to that i cant set refresh() to static, because of its inside codes...

Comment: Put your `AsyncTask` code as an inner class of your Main `Activity`. In that way the `onPostExecute(...)` method can directly call the `refresh(...)` method.

Comment: oh yes..! your right...it was a good idea my friend.thank you for your help <3